# In music what is style as it relates to instruments?

Tags: composition, keyboard, ear-training, styles, accompaniment

In music what is style I mean accompaniment styles? How does one play with style as it relates to instruments? Like make their own 16 ballad style.   https://musicterms.artopium.com/s/Style.htm obviously you guys didn't see accompaniment style on keyboard. I want to know how audio accompaniments are made with style and what makes it a style. Come on people work with me here.

Comment: Do you mean the piano style of Chopin, Liszt, or harpsichord style in the time of Bach and Händel? Guitar style like Flamenco and Gypsy? Baroque trumpet? Maybe you are  looking for dances or Suites?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ethnic styles of music that use instrumentation that is native to the part of the world that the style originates from. East Indian music is one style and uses a lot of sitar. Then there is African Music that incorporates a lot of percussion instruments. Perhaps you might consider Choral music a style, it uses primarily voices as its instrumentation, or maybe church music which until recently was associated with organ music. There are just too many examples for a person not to notice, Marching Bands, Symphonies, Polka Music, Skittle Bands, Harmonica Bands, Folk Music, Klezmer music, Elevator music. I think we need a little help in narrowing down the question to a sharper point in order to give a decent reply.